# Google Appengine backend logging on local dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do you get logging out of an appengine backend during local development? I tried logging, logservice.flush(). No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Logging works, but the default logging level is `WARNING`, so logging.info() or logging.debug() won't show up.

You can set the logging level when starting your dev server:

```
dev_appserver.py --log_level=debug ...
```

From [dev_appserver.py command-line arguments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?hl=en#Python_Command-line_arguments):

> --log_level=...
>
> The lowest logging level at which logging messages will be written to the console; messages of the specified logging level or higher will
>   be output. Possible values are debug, info, warning, error, and
>   critical.

You can also [persist your logs to a file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/#Python_The_development_server_and_Logs_API):

> By default, logs are stored in memory only in the development server
>   and are accessible if you wish to test the Logs API feature. If you
>   wish to persist logs from the development server to disk at the
>   default location /tmp/dev_appserver.logs, supply the --persist_logs
>   command line option as follows:
>
> ```
> dev_appserver.py --persist_logs your-app-directory
> ```
>
> If you wish to persist the logs from the development server to disk at
>   a location of your own choosing, supply the desired path and filename
>   to the --logs_path command line option as follows:
>
> ```
> dev_appserver.py --logs_path=your-path/your-logfile-name your-app-directory
> ```